# Get related item many to many

Tags: php, yii2

I have model post and tags. And relationship many-to-many.

Post:

```
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tag::className(), ['id' => 'tag_id'])
        ->viaTable('post_tag', ['post_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Tags:

```
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::className(), ['id' => 'post_id'])
        ->viaTable('post_tag', ['post_id' => 'id']);
}
```

And table post-tags:

But when I try tags for post:

```
 $tags = $post->tags;
```

I get an empty variable;

```
-------------------------
|    Post-tag table:    |
-------------------------
| id | post_id | tag_id |
-------------------------
| 8  |   2     |   1    |
-------------------------
```

Comment: do you have relevant tags saved against the `post` inside the `post_tag` table for which you are calling the relation? what is in the `$post`

Comment: also, you have an incorrect relation for the `getPosts()` inside the `Tags` model, it should be `->viaTable('post_tag',['tag_id'=>'id']);`

Comment: MuhammadOmerAslam got the point. There was a typo in your `getPosts`

Comment: $post = Post::findOne($id);
       $tags=$post->getTags();

Comment: post- instanse of post.  $post = Post::findOne($id);

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the relevant tags saved in the `post_tag` table against the `post` you are calling the relation.

Also you have to correct the relation inside the `Tags` Model, you need to specify the `'tag_id'=>'id'` rather than `'post_id'=>'id'` when calling `viaTable()`.

```
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::className(), ['id' => 'post_id'])
            ->viaTable('post_tag',['tag_id'=>'id']);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Posts:

```
public function getTags() {
    return $this->hasMany ( Tag::className (), [ 
            'post_id' => 'post_id' 
    ] )
}
```

Tags:

no need actually;

```
public function getPosts() {
    return $this->hasMany ( Post::className (), [ 
            'post_id' => 'post_id' 
    ] )
}
```

`$tags = $post->tags;` will give u an object now!